# How do I use the fadeIn effect in CakePHP with jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm new to JavaScript and I'm finding it especially confusing in CakePHP.

I have an AJAX call that fetches another page and places it in a div. This works, but I would like it to fade in instead of just appearing.

This is the code I have so far:

```
$this->Js->get('#load_items');
$this->Js->event('click', $this->Js->request(
    array('action' => 'plain_items'),
    array(
        'async' => true, 
        'update' => '#items',
        'complete' => 'onComplete'
    )
));
$this->Js->event('onComplete', $this->Js->effect('fadeIn'));

echo '<div id="items"></div>';
echo $this->Form->submit('Load Items', array('id' => 'load_items'));
```

This has no issues getting the "plain_items" view and loading it in the "items" div, but I cannot get it to fade it when it loads. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

$this->Js this contains object of #load_items, if you want to fade in div #items, then you need to take oject of this div and then do fade in.. see below example

```
$this->Js->event('click', $this->Js->request(
    array('action' => 'plain_items'),
    array(
        'async' => true, 
        'update' => '#items',
        'before' => $this->Js->get('#items')->effect('fadeOut', array('buffer' => false)),
        'complete' => $this->Js->get('#items')->effect('fadeIn', array('buffer' => false))
    )
));
```

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't look like 'onComplete' is every getting called. Do I have the syntax wrong in order to call that?

Comment: That works better, but I should have mentioned that this is triggered by a submit button. Your fix works if you click on the div, but not the submit button. #load_items is the id of the button.

Comment: Have you tried it ? because it bind to ajax complete means it should fadein after your div updated by ajax

Comment: I did try it, but it will only load/fade if you click the div. It won't do it if you click the submit button. The source code has $("#items").bind("click" instead of $("#load_items").bind("click"